# Is it possible to use references in JSON?

Tags: python, json, yaml

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "app_name": "my_app",
    "version": {
        "1.0": {
            "path": "/my_app/1.0"
        },
        "2.0": {
            "path": "/my_app/2.0"   
        }
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to reference the keywords `app_name` and the key of `version` so that I don't have to repeat "my_app" and the version numbering?

I was thinking something along the lines of... (code totally made up):

```
{
    "@app_name": "my_app",
    "version": {
        "1.0": {
            "path": "/{{$app_name}}/{{key[-1]]}}"
        },
        "2.0": {
            "path": "/{{$app_name}}/{{key[-1]}}"    
        }
    }
}
```

Or is this something that could instead be handled better using YAML?

In the end, I intend to read this data into a Python dictionary.

Comment: I would assume `{{$key}}` refers to `"path"` and not to `"1.0"`

Comment: I found [jsonref](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonref) which enables references in JSON. I just don't think I can grab the relative references to keys using it (meaning grabbing `1.0` and `2.0` in my pseudo code above).

Comment: @Anthon yeah, you're right. I edited it into saying something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JSON does not have references. (The functionality you request here, with substring expansion, would open itself to memory attacks against the parser; by not supporting this functionality, JSON avoids vulnerability to such attacks).

If you want such functionality, you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Can you please provide a source with regards to attacks on YAML based on the references functionality? I can only find vulnerabilities based on object instantiation as a result of tagging.

Comment: @Anthon, I'm referring in this case to memory amplification attacks -- those have also been done against XML extensions offering the same functionality, leveraging nested inclusions to generate documents that take a small amount of bandwidth to transfer but a large amount of memory to parse. Hence DOS attacks, not code-execution attacks (as the ones you referenced above).

Comment: Interesting concept. I am going to run some tests to see what level of amplification you can get in Python. I see a bigger problem when using references for merging dictionaries, as most parsers expand those on reading (the one exception I know is my ruamel.yaml parser for Python in round-trip mode).

Comment: You are talking about inclusions in XML which have nothing to do with references in YAML. Since references in YAML are strictly ordered (you cannot reference an object below the current position), a single-pass interpretation is always possible and therefore, memory consumption related to references is in O(n). I challenge the claim that YAML is vulnerable to such attacks and kindly ask you to provide evidence of it.

Comment: "O(n)" does not follow from "single-pass interpretation is always possible". **If** the substring expansion functionality the OP requests here is available (and I don't know if it is), then an example with greater-than-O(n) memory usage is outright trivial, via a series of `"s1": "string here"`, `"s2": "{{$s1}}{{$s1}}{{$s1}}...", "s3": "{{$s2}}{{$s2}}{{$s2}}...", "s4": {{$s3}}{{$s3}}{{$s3}}..."`, etc. If the OP's assertion in the question about that functionality's availability is false, then of course so is my conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Not in pure JSON, but you could performs string substitution after you parse the JSON.